# elasticsearchRestTemplate convert json to java code

Tags: elasticsearch

```
 /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "word": "aac"
    }
    
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
   
    "recordId":{
        "terms":{
            "field":"recordId.keyword",
            "size":10,
            "min_doc_count":1,
            "shard_min_doc_count":0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error":false,
             "order":[
                {
                    "maxScore":"desc"
                },
                {
                    "_key":"asc"
                }
            ]
           
        },
        "aggregations":{
            "maxScore":{
                "max":{
                    "script":"_score"
                }
            },
            "result":{
                        "top_hits":{
                            "from":0,
                            "size":3,
                            "version":false,
                            "seq_no_primary_term":false,
                            "explain":false
                        }
                    }
        }
 
    }
    }

}
```

how to convert result to java code ?

```
        TermsAggregationBuilder terms = AggregationBuilders.terms(fnToFieldName(MediaRecognizeDocument::getRecordId))
                .field(fnToFieldName(MediaRecognizeDocument::getRecordId) + ".keyword").size(10)
                .order(BucketOrder.aggregation("maxScore", false))
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.max("maxScore")
                        .script(new Script("_score")));
```

TermsAggregationBuilder terms = AggregationBuilders.terms(fnToFieldName(MediaRecognizeDocument::getRecordId))
.field(fnToFieldName(MediaRecognizeDocument::getRecordId) + ".keyword").size(10)
.order(BucketOrder.aggregation("maxScore", false))
.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.max("maxScore")
.script(new Script("_score")));